# react-native: multi color text view

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to render a single line of text with some words highlighted in a different color.

I would ideally do it with a span tag with react.

Wondering how would i do the same with react-native?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can achieve this by using nested Text components

```
<Text style={{color: 'blue'}}>
    I am blue
    <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>
        i am red
    </Text>
    and i am blue again
</Text>
```

Here's a [link](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#nested-text) to the documentation explaining it better

Comment: What if you have dynamic text? Imagine text is from server with some placeholders to signify that the client should highlight.

Comment: That's quite specific, so it's not provided by default. It shouldn't be that hard to accomplish though. Try writing a specific function that parses the string from the server and outputs an object that contains the styles to apply to each substring. Then you can feed this object to a custom component that renders nested Text components like the one above.

Comment: Ya. That makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

Simply nest `<Text>` elements

```
<Text>
    I am some text with 
    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>bold</Text> 
    stuff
<Text>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it better, my way:

```
CText = (props) => <Text style={{color: props.color}}>{props.children}</Text>
```

inside render add:

```
const CText = this.CText
```

and return

```
<Text>I am <CText color={'red'}>Blue color</CText> and <CText color={'blue'}>Blue color</CText></Text>
```