# React Native TextInput different background colors for different letters/characters?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, colors, react-native

I know I can set the background for a TextInput, but I want to change the background color of parts of the TextInput to highlight certain letters.

I don't know if this is possible at all (React Native newbie here)

I'm making a field where the user has to type text that matches exactly. I wanted to have the letters they got right highlighted in green and then highlight anything wrong in red by changing the background color.

If TextInput doesn't allow multiple background colors, I guess I could try [nested Text components like in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29372897/8050097). I'm thinking of having a TextInput for input, but then updating some other part of the UI on each key press making each new character a new Text component which can have it's backgroundColor set red/green.
Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
CText = (props) => <Text style={{backgroungColor: props.backgroungColor}}>{props.children}</Text>
```

inside render add:

```
const CText = this.CText
```

and return

```
<Text>I am <CText backgroungColor={'red'}>Blue color</CText> and <CText backgroungColor={'blue'}>Blue color</CText></Text>
```